# How to change image while i change the option on select using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

here is my code which is not working.

```
<select id="pa_color" class="" name="attribute_pa_color" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_color" data-show_option_none="yes">
<option value="">Choose an option</option>
<option value="type-1-red" class="attached enabled">type 1 red</option>
<option value="type-1-rose-glod" class="attached enabled">type 1 rose glod</option>
<option value="type-2-red" class="attached enabled">type 2 red</option>
<option value="type-2-rose-glod" class="attached enabled">type 2 rose glod</option>
</select>

<img id="image-custom" src="https://sparklesection.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Portable-LED-Makeup-Mirror-Adjustable-Lighted-Mini-Circular-Travel-Sensing-Lighting-Cosmetic-Mirror-Wireless-USB-Charging-3.jpg" height="auto" width="20%">



<script>

    var colorUrlMap = {
        "type-1-red": "https://sparklesection.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Portable-LED-Makeup-Mirror-Adjustable-Lighted-Mini-Circular-Travel-Sensing-Lighting-Cosmetic-Mirror-Wireless-USB-Charging-3.jpg_640x640-3.jpg",
        "type-1-rose-glod": "https://sparklesection.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Portable-LED-Makeup-Mirror-Adjustable-Lighted-Mini-Circular-Travel-Sensing-Lighting-Cosmetic-Mirror-Wireless-USB-Charging-2.jpg_640x640-2.jpg",
        "type-2-red": "https://sparklesection.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Portable-LED-Makeup-Mirror-Adjustable-Lighted-Mini-Circular-Travel-Sensing-Lighting-Cosmetic-Mirror-Wireless-USB-Charging-1.jpg_640x640-1.jpg",
        "type-2-rose-glod": "https://sparklesection.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Portable-LED-Makeup-Mirror-Adjustable-Lighted-Mini-Circular-Travel-Sensing-Lighting-Cosmetic-Mirror-Wireless-USB-Charging.jpg_640x640.jpg"
    };

    document.getElementById('pa_color').addEventListener('onchange', function() {
                document.getElementById('image-custom').src = colorUrlMap[this.value];
    }


</script>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code ? Or can anyone solve it ?

Comment: The `id` is `image-custom` and not `custom-image`. Also the event on `addEventListener` is written wrongly.

Comment: still same, not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing you can do for yourself in debugging problems is to look at the error messages. Running your code there is a clear error that says you are missing a `)` after argument list. Your first problem is you are missing a closing `)` after calling `.addEventListener()`. Your second problem is instead of `onchange` you need to be using `change` when calling `.addEventListener()`.

```js
var colorUrlMap = {
  "type-1-red": "https://sparklesection.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Portable-LED-Makeup-Mirror-Adjustable-Lighted-Mini-Circular-Travel-Sensing-Lighting-Cosmetic-Mirror-Wireless-USB-Charging-3.jpg_640x640-3.jpg",
  "type-1-rose-glod": "https://sparklesection.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Portable-LED-Makeup-Mirror-Adjustable-Lighted-Mini-Circular-Travel-Sensing-Lighting-Cosmetic-Mirror-Wireless-USB-Charging-2.jpg_640x640-2.jpg",
  "type-2-red": "https://sparklesection.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Portable-LED-Makeup-Mirror-Adjustable-Lighted-Mini-Circular-Travel-Sensing-Lighting-Cosmetic-Mirror-Wireless-USB-Charging-1.jpg_640x640-1.jpg",
  "type-2-rose-glod": "https://sparklesection.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Portable-LED-Makeup-Mirror-Adjustable-Lighted-Mini-Circular-Travel-Sensing-Lighting-Cosmetic-Mirror-Wireless-USB-Charging.jpg_640x640.jpg"
};

document.getElementById('pa_color').addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.getElementById('image-custom').src = colorUrlMap[this.value];
})
```

```html
<select id="pa_color" class="" name="attribute_pa_color" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_color" data-show_option_none="yes">
<option value="">Choose an option</option>
<option value="type-1-red" class="attached enabled">type 1 red</option>
<option value="type-1-rose-glod" class="attached enabled">type 1 rose glod</option>
<option value="type-2-red" class="attached enabled">type 2 red</option>
<option value="type-2-rose-glod" class="attached enabled">type 2 rose glod</option>
</select>

<img id="image-custom" src="https://sparklesection.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Portable-LED-Makeup-Mirror-Adjustable-Lighted-Mini-Circular-Travel-Sensing-Lighting-Cosmetic-Mirror-Wireless-USB-Charging-3.jpg" height="auto" width="20%">
```

Comment: thank you, i am stupid and noob , But you saved me :D